# Java Enum equals

Tags: java, enums

```
class Enum{
    enum Season { WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new Enum().pf());
        }

    String pf() {
         if (Season.WINTER.equals("WINTER")) return "equal";
         else return "not equal";
     }
}
```

Why the result is not equal. Is that because Season.WINTER is an object, not a String? I am not sure? And when we can get "equal" result?

Comment: Think about it that way: would you expect `"WINTER".equals(Season.WINTER)` to return `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing an enumerated type with a `String`, which will return `false`.

You can invoke `name()` on your enum type to compare it with a `String`.

Otherwise, you can use a `switch` statement.

See also, implementation of `equals` for enums (source from Oracle Java 8):

```
/**
 * Returns true if the specified object is equal to this
 * enum constant.
 *
 * @param other the object to be compared for equality with this object.
 * @return  true if the specified object is equal to this
 *          enum constant.
 */
public final boolean equals(Object other) {
    return this==other;
}
```

As you can see from the example, the implementation for `enum`s is the same as for `Object`, i.e. it only compares the reference.